# Windows 7 - Login into windows using touch screen keyboard

Tags: windows-7, on-screen-keyboard

My company makes a sort of terminal that uses a touchscreen as the **only** user interface. There is a mouse and keyboard set connected to the PC running the terminal, however they are both safely locked away.

The user account logins automatically on startup, however every once in a while someone will use a remote desktop connection to connect to the terminal - and doing so log out the active user. When that happens the client's shift manager has to go find the key to the physical access to the terminal's keyboard set in order to login, which I am told is very annoying (I can imagine).

I configured the on-screen keyboard (in Ease of Access Center) to show the on-screen keyboard on the login screen. I thought that was a nice workaround, however since the screen begins with **"Press Ctr+Alt+Del in order to login"** I was back to square one, since the on-screen keyboard won't allow the user to enter Ctr+Alt+Del...

Is there a configuration option I'm missing? How do I enable the user to login without touching the physical keyboard?

Comment: There's a setting to skip the Ctrl+Alt+Del and go straight to the list of user accounts. I can't remember the setting though and can't look it up right now, so this is just a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **netplwiz** from the Start Menu. Click on the Advanced tab and at the bottom of the page there's a "Require users to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete" checkbox. Try unchecking it.

If it's a corporate machine and you can/want to modify GPO settings then it's also possible. But depends a bit on what version of Windows Server you're using

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Is it by any chance possible to set Remote Desktop Connection so it doesn't logout the active user (or logs the user back in when RDC is disconnected?)